# Integrate Code Snippet in Wordpress (Html & Css)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, code-snippets, codepen

I know this question is really dumb, but I have this code (for a pricetable) here:
https://codepen.io/VoloshchenkoAl/pen/NABNoN

I tried to copy paste it with a shortcode, that looks like this:

```
         <script>
              
                //css code here
</script>

//and then pasted html code here
```

But the outcome looks like this:
[my version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvIwB.png)

How can I fix that and make it look like the Snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not interpreting(use) the CSS. Make sure to place the CSS in appropriate places.

And don't use common class names which WordPress uses.

Comment: Where should I place the CSS then? The problem is, I dont want to change the whole Design of the Website

Comment: @ekalem WP themes provide that feature. E.g. Custom CSS. There you can add your CSS queries.
*Use your own/ unique class names. Then it won't affect the existing definitions.

Comment: Yeah, I did change the class names in html/css and put the css code on additional css. But unfortunately it still looks the same

Comment: Ok I found the problem. It was a SCSS Code. I just needed to convert it to normal CSS. But still thanks a lot :)